# window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage not working in React JS for passing data from WebViews to React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, postmessage, react-native-webview

I have a Web Application in React JS which is hosted in Netlify. The same is embedded in React Native using WebViews. I want to pass data from React JS to React Native.

I tried `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("hello")` in React JS, but the `onMessage` is not being invoked in React Native Webview.

React JS Code -

```
await window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("Hello!");
```

React Native Code -

```
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'hosted netlify link' }}
        ref={webViewRef}

        onMessage={(event) =>
          { 
          console.log("INSIDE ON MESSAGE"); 
          alert(event.nativeEvent.data); }
          }

        style={styles.view}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        scalesPageToFit
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid
        useWebkit
        startInLoadingState={true}
        renderLoading={Spinner}
        geolocationEnabled={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Please help me in passing data from React JS to React Native.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try without the await?

Comment: Yeah I tried without the await too, its not working

Comment: Ok, can you also try injecting the post message code from React Native to webview to see if it works?

Comment: You are asking me to try vice versa right?

Comment: Try adding this prop to your webview, just to test that it works. 
injectedJavaScript={'window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("Hello!");'}

Comment: @miknoup I tried this and its working, I don't know why it isn't working from React JS

Comment: Try running code from React JS when page is fully loaded.
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
};

Comment: @miknoup no that isn't working, so is the problem with my "window" ??

Comment: I think you should find a way to defer the call to postMessage when your React js page is fully loaded.

Comment: @miknoup In my actual code, the `postMessage` is executed only when a button is clicked in React JS. So at that time the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for a while, here is a working solution that solved my issue.

On your React JS side add the following to post the message to React Native:

```
  window["ReactNativeWebView"] && window["ReactNativeWebView"].postMessage(JSON.stringify({"key": "value"})).
```

Please note that you must pass only one **string** argument.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code:

**React JS code:**

```
          window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ message: "your message" , data: "your data"}));
```

**React-native code:**

```
function handleVideoEvents(event) {
    let eventObj = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data)
    let message = eventObj.message
    let data = eventObj.data
    console.log('message :', message)
    console.log('data :', data)
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'hosted netlify link' }}
        ref={webViewRef}
        onMessage={event => handleVideoEvents(event)}
        style={styles.view}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        scalesPageToFit
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid
        useWebkit
        startInLoadingState={true}
        renderLoading={Spinner}
        geolocationEnabled={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: I tried this one, still, the `onMessage` is not invoked. Please let me know if you need any other information from my code.

Comment: is there any other method to pass data from React JS to React Native using WebViews?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue. In the ReactJS code, it shows an empty object `{}` when I run the code below:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  alert(JSON.stringify(window.ReactNativeWebView));
});
</script>
```

I'm using React Native v71. It used to work normally with v69